# Doubts about js number representation and his bit operation？

Tags: javascript

I know that js numbers are represented by 64-bit floating point types. HereI can clearly see how these 64 bits are.

[image]

For example, -1 means

[image]

So when two numbers are bitwise operated, does it have anything to do with the 64-bit number representation? Through my tests, integers behave like two 32-bit numbers, such as the following example:

```
    -1 & 5   // 5
    -1 & 2**31  // -2147483648
    -1 & 2**32  // 0
```

So my question is, will they behave like 32-bit numbers when performing bitwise calculations on two numbers? Just like int in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR:

No. JS converts floats to ints.

### Full details:

JavaScript engines perform the bitwise operations `~`, `&`, `^`, `|` (but not `>>`, `<<`, and `>>>`) only on 32-bit integer values - so JS engines need to convert floating-point values and any non-integer values to 32-bit integers first. This does mean that bitwise operations are lossy if your operands are non-integral.

---

> I know that js numbers are represented by 64-bit floating point types

This is an oversimplification. It's true that `Number` values can behave externally like a 64-bit IEEE-754 number ("double precision float"), but internally engines have a lot of lee-way, in addition to the spec requiring bitwise operations for integral values, which would be meaningless on floating values. This is because `Number` can represent both integral and floating values and it's up to the programmer to ensure they're suitably-value'd before performing bitwise operations. JS doesn't complain if you try to do a bitwise XOR between a 32-bit integer and a 64-bit float.

> So when two numbers are bitwise operated, does it have anything to do with the 64-bit number representation?

I think you meant to ask:

> When two numbers are bitwise operated, does it perform the bitwise operation on their IEEE-754 binary representation or not?

The answer is "no". **Bitwise operations are not performed on IEEE 754 binary representations**. JS's bitwise operators actually cause the JS engine to convert the (IEEE-754 floating) value to a 32-bit integer:

To quote MDN, emphasis mine:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND
>
> **The operands are converted to 32-bit integers** and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits discarded.

The exact process is described in the ECMAScript spec 6.1.6.1.16 `NumberBitwiseOp` (emphasis mine):

> https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numberbitwiseop
>
> The abstract operation NumberBitwiseOp takes arguments op (a sequence of Unicode code points), x, and y. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Assert: op is &, ^, or |.
> 2. Let lnum be ! ToInt32(x).
> 3. Let rnum be ! ToInt32(y).
> 4. **Let lbits be the 32-bit two's complement bit string representing ℝ(lnum)**.
> 5. **Let rbits be the 32-bit two's complement bit string representing ℝ(rnum)**.
> 6. If op is &, let result be the result of applying the bitwise AND operation to lbits and rbits.
> 7. Else if op is ^, let result be the result of applying the bitwise exclusive OR (XOR) operation to lbits and rbits.
> 8. Else, op is |. Let result be the result of applying the bitwise inclusive OR operation to lbits and rbits.
> 9. Return the Number value for the integer represented by the 32-bit two's complement bit string result.

---